# I am using NodeJs for building e-commerce app. However, axios is not defined error occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using axios for ecommerce app. when I launch the app I can see a below error in console.

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: axios is not defined
at getProducts (main.js:5)
at main.js:8

I have tried to import axios at top of the file.
I have tried by installing axios.

but still not working
here is my main.js code

```
    const axios = require('axios');
    async function getProducts() {
     const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/products');
     console.log(response.data);
     }
      getProducts();
```

Comment: did you installed axios by `npm install axios` or `yarn add axios` ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have installed using npm install axios.

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file and you are executing the correct file? The `ReferenceError: axios is not defined at `  error would not match the shown code. The error will occur when `const axios;` is not present. But is unrelated to whether `axios` is installed or not.

Comment: Sometimes removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and reinstall `npm i` may work.

Comment: I think you're not showing us the REAL code because ReferenceError will be caused when `axios` is not defined, but you're showing it defined so there's definitely more to the real code that we need to see.

Answer (score 0):

Please tried below format:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const sendGetRequest = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

sendGetRequest();
```

Comment: `ReferenceError` is not related to something being installed or not, but whether a variable is declared or not.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need axios on your backend, you can fetch data directly with your defined API's.
Use axios on your frontend with that API, that should work.

Try the following,
app.get('http://localhost:5000/products')

If you are using router from express then you can try router.get('http://localhost:5000/products')

Comment: `app.get('http://localhost:5000/products')` is not for making http requests to other servers.

Comment: not other servers, as he has mentioned that he is using nodejs, routes will be defined by himself. So, you can use app.get( ) if you are using express and fetch data. You can check that in postman or directly on the browser

Comment: The OP's code `await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/products');` is trying to MAKE an http request.  Besides `app.get('http://localhost:5000/products')` isn't even a proper way to define a route for an Express server anyway.

Comment: I am talking from the backend perspective, from frontend you can use axios. When you want to check the routes you defined on your backend sever how else would you do?